# java oracle jdbc resultset empty but record is available in the table

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I'm running java 1.8 connecting to  oracle 12c using ojdbc7.jar for jdbc connection.

This is the code that execute to retrieve the data

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + 
         ipAddress + ":1521:" + dbname,userName,password);  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
String query = "select * from table_name";
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

but the code is not entering the while loop.

When i try exeuction the same query in DB, I could see the table has 10 entries.

Does anyone know what could be the reason?

Comment: You are supposed to execute the query first. Like `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);` .

Comment: `query` is never used

Comment: sorry, my bad and its the worst mistake.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + 
         ipAddress + ":1521:" + dbname,userName,password); 
       Statement  stmt = con.createStatement();
       String query = "select * from table_name";
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
       while (rs.next()) { 
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }

  } catch (SQLException e ) {

  } finally {
    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
  }
```